# Abnormal flag weight

Tags: support, flagging

Today, when I looked at my profile, I noticed my Flag weight is a decimal. How is this possible?

[image]

Are you using some vintage Pentiums maybe? ([Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug)) :-)

Comment: Thank you for making me feel old by needing to put the Pentium crack in context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight

Specifically:

> Why is my flag weight not an integer?
>
> Because flag weight above 500 does not increase in a linear fashion, decimal places are shown for precision purposes and to show you how your flag weight is changing.